# How to use snowflakes in reactive applications or R2DBC support for snowflake?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, spring-webflux, r2dbc

To use postgres with reactive application, we can use -

```
api 'io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql:0.8.10.RELEASE'

spring:
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:postgresql://host:port/db
```

Is there similar R2DBC support for snowflake?
or
How can we use snowflakes in reactive applications?

Comment: There isn't any R2DBC support for Snowflake as of now as far as I can see.

Comment: After searching a lot. Did not found any R2DBC support for Snowflake, finally moved to JDBC non reactive approach.